# .NET 7 console application using EF Core 7 why no OnConfiguring?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-power-tools

I built a database first .NET 7 and EF Core 7 application and used the EF Power Tools to create the context and model classes. I keep reading about `OnConfiguring()` being in the context class. I only have `OnModelCreating()`? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. You can still override [`DbContext.OnConfiguring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-7.0) in your context if you want to but with modern patterns using DI it is rarely needed (unless you are using something like [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors)).

See also:

- If you want connection string added via `OnConfiguring` enable [Include connection string in generated code](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#choose-options) option (note that this should not be used in production level apps)
- [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Comment: Thanks. I shall read that. I reran the Power Tools and checked the box concerning the connection string. I now have a connections and a OnConfiguring().

Answer (score 1):

As @Guru Stron said above, you haven't done anything wrong!

if you **do** need to provide additional configuration options for your context, you can override the DbContextOptionsBuilder in the OnConfiguring() method.

For example:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection-string-placeholder");
  }
}
```